# if-statement gives another result than expected

Tags: php, if-statement

I need help with this bit of PHP, it's an if-statement. Depending on the usertype will display a different nav bars. All I'm getting `global/i-super_nav.php`

```
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION["Member_type"]) && $_SESSION["Member_type"]== 'S'){
    include ('global/i-super_nav.php');
}
elseif(isset($_SESSION["Member_type"]) && $_SESSION["Member_type"]== 'A'){
    include ('global/i-admin_nav.php');
}
elseif(isset($_SESSION["Member_type"]) && $_SESSION["Member_type"]== 'U'){
    include ('global/i-member_nav.php');
}
else
{
    include ('global/i-nav.php');
}
```

Comment: Describe your problem, add more information and tell us what you want to do.

Comment: Do an `echo $_SESSION["Member_type"]` to see what it is printing

Comment: do a var_dump of $_SESSION['member_type'] this will show you the content

Comment: It looks like your `$_SESSION["Member_type"]` is *always* equal to `S`.  Why is that?  You need to look at where you set it

Comment: Salvaged the answer a biy, should be more clear now :)

Comment: If you have a problom with the statmen you might have to display a different solutions.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: You have to check where you are making this session and what you are passing in session.

Comment: For all the downvoters: This answer is asking for "how to debug", only the TS doesn't know that. We should see that this isn't a programming problem perse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The if-statements you use are quite straightforward, the only possibility is that `$_SESSION["Member_type"]` always is the value `"S"`. This means that the 'problem' is something else.

You can easily verify this yourself. Right before you do the if-statement, you place `print_r($_SESSION)`. If you do that, you'll see the values in the session array. It could be lowercased, or maybe simple set wrong.

*This should always be your first test (to check the actual value, not what you think it is).*

---

And while we're at it, let's add a bit of a code review. For what you've made, is another method which is more common to implement, the [`switch()`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php):

```
switch( strtoupper($_SESSION["Member_type"]) ){
    case 'S':
        include ('global/i-super_nav.php');
    break;
    case 'A':
        include ('global/i-admin_nav.php');
    break;
    case 'U':
        include ('global/i-member_nav.php');
    break;
    default:
        include ('global/i-nav.php');
    break;
}
```

I've added the [`strtoupper()`](http://php.net/strtoupper). This way, if your value is `S` or `s`, it'll work. Using string like that isn't optimal, thats why we often use numbers, but this way you made it a bit more stupidproof :)

Answer (score 0):

Your if statement looks fine.

But look carefully at the code where you set your `$_SESSION["Member_type"]` variable.  Your code may always be setting it to value `"S"`